# Sublime Error when trying to build php code

Tags: php, linux, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to code in linux with Sublime. I cannot run my code,a mistake occurs. I went to Tools > Build System > New build system and wrote this:

```
{
"cmd": ["php", "$file"],
"selector": "source.php",
"file_regex":"php$"
}
```

When I click CTRL + B this pops up:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'php'
[cmd: ['php', '/home/osboxes/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/test.php']]
[dir: /home/osboxes/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User]
[path: /home/osboxes/bin:/home/osboxes/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: have you installed php-cli?

Answer (score 0):

You need the **path** to the `php` (executable file). I assume that the file is in `/usr/bin/php`.

```
{
    "cmd": ["//usr//bin//php", "$file"], 
    "file_regex": "php$",    
     "selector": "source.php"
}
```

**Hint**

If it is a different path, you can search on the terminal with 
`sudo find /usr -name php`.